# How would I go about boundary breaking Madagascar for the PC?

Tags: mods, madagascar

I have the files for the Madagascar game for the PC, which I'm very interested in looking into the development of. Specifically, I'd like to perform a sort of boundary-break (i.e. develop/download a free look camera mod). However, any kind of modding advice is appreciated. I'm skilled in programming so happy to learn any languages I may need.
(The game was downloaded here:
https://oldgamesdownload.com/madagascar/)

Comment: This is a very broad question, and as Arqade is a site made up of (mostly) just gamers rather than specifically programmers or modders, I'm not sure we have the expertise on hand to help you out. Unless you're specifically looking for in-game glitches that help you boundary break, you may have better luck on more modding-specific communities.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this might be the case but I wasn't sure where else to ask. Would you happen to know of any specific sites on which I could ask my question?